# How can I copy a vector to the end of another vector?

Tags: c++

I have been working on what I thought would just be a simple function for quite a while now. We are expected to use `push_back()`, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here's what I have right now:

```cpp
void append(const vector<int>& v1, vector<int> v2)
{
    for (int x : v1)
        v2.push_back(x);
}

void println(const vector<int>& v)
{
    for (int x : v)
        cout << x << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector <int> v1(3, 15);
    vector <int> v2(3, 25);
    append(v1, v2);
    println(v1);
    println(v2);
}
```

Comment: Vectors have an `insert` function that does that already.

Comment: You are passing v2 to append by value. Pass it by reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v2` in `void append(const vector<int>& v1, vector<int> v2)` is a *copy* of what is passed, so modifying it won't affect what is passed.

You should use reference (add `&`) to have the function modify what is passed.

```
void append(const vector<int>& v1, vector<int>& v2) // add & before v2
{
    for (int x : v1)
        v2.push_back(x);
}
```

If you are not expected to use `push_back`, [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is useful.

```
#include <algorithm>

void append(const vector<int>& v1, vector<int>& v2)
{
    std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2));
}
```

Comment: In this case `v2.insert(v2.end(), v1.begin(), v1.end())` may be better than `std::copy`